# Vagrant Authentication

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I'm new to vagrant and attempting to setup a precise64 box using VirtualBox on Windows 10 as per the vagrant getting started guide.

When I run 'vagrant up' the box boots when I check VirtualBox but doesn't get past the login prompt.

Here is my vagrant file;

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  config.ssh.username = 'vagrant'
  config.ssh.password = 'vagrant'
  config.ssh.insert_key = 'true'

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  # config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  #   vb.memory = "1024"
  # end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Define a Vagrant Push strategy for pushing to Atlas. Other push strategies
  # such as FTP and Heroku are also available. See the documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/push/atlas.html for more information.
  # config.push.define "atlas" do |push|
  #   push.app = "YOUR_ATLAS_USERNAME/YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME"
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
  # config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  #   apt-get update
  #   apt-get install -y apache2
  # SHELL
end
```

When I run vagrant up it pauses here for a couple of minutes;

```
C:\HashiCorp>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/precise64' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: password
```

before giving me the following message;

```
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

> Note: If I access the box directly I'm unable to login with the
>   username as 'root' but I can login with the username 'vagrant' and the
>   password 'vagrant'.

Comment: What version of Vagrant? This isn't 1.8.5 by any chance is it?

Comment: Vagrant 1.9.0. I should have mentioned I'm using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove

```
  config.ssh.username = 'vagrant'
  config.ssh.password = 'vagrant'
```

vagrant is the default username so it does not need to be mentioned and it authenticates with a private key and not by password by default (specially on this box)

also you mention you're new so I am not sure you need to take care about ssh key for now. I would also suggest you remove

```
 config.ssh.insert_key = 'true'
```

unless you know what you're doing

Comment: I think `config.ssh.insert_key = 'true'` is the default option since 1.8 though anyway.

Comment: Indeed @MattSchuchard is fully right and now it is true by default, there were a lot of discussion about vagrant being insecure by default. so as you keep default value in your Vagrantfile you can just remove this line too

Comment: Thanks, I've removed these to keep with the defaults. I'm still no further forward with getting vagrant to automatically log in to the box unfortunately.